# Extracting Page Source with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Is there a way to extract the whole source page in exactly same way as you would be seeing it when you click rmb 'View page source' on a browser, just a raw page with thousands of lines of text?. I've tried requests.get(), but I'm only getting a fraction of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://whateverpage.com')
x = browser.page_source

print(x)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.